# How to make a web browser bot?

Tags: c#

I have searched this site and other sites for an answer that would help me but I just can't get the codes I come across to work for me.

First let me explain how my program works and where I am at with it, then let me explain what I am trying to do but can't get it to work.

1st: I have Form1 as a login to a website. You enter the Username and Password that you would use to log into that website and you can also have it log you in automatically and have it remember your login information.

2nd: After you login, Form3 opens up (Form2 is the about me), You have a web browser and a button below (there will be more buttons below the browser but first i have to get this button working.)

3rd: The problem is that when I click the button I have it go to a web address and then I want it to hire my offensive and deffensive troops and then click submit (the hire troops buttons and submit button are on the website.) The hire troops is a text field on the website and next to it there is a max offense and max deffense button. Now what I want it to do is click the Max offense and then click the Max deffense button and the click the submit button.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [WatiN](http://watin.org/) - it allows you to automate browser and script actions like typing into textbox or clicking buttons.

Comment: Ok, I have seen this before and tried it and I just tried it again, but it dosen't work for me or at least I can't get it to work. I'm not using an actuall web browser that opens up, I'm using a .net web browser that is put onto the form so that I can view the website.

Comment: The link has died, you might want to replace it. Maybe use [this one](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/658947/Watin-An-Automation-Testing-in-NET) ?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the button IDs by **right click -> inspect element**. After you get all the ID`s you need, enter the troop hiring url to your WebBrowser URL property. Finally, on your submit button's click event, enter the following code:

```
private void Submit(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string amountOffensiveUnits = "enter amount";
            string amountDeffensiveUnits = "enter amount";

            try
            {
                //LoginScreen_webBrowser.Document.GetElementById("Offensive_txt_id").InnerText = User_Name_txt.Text;
                //LoginScreen_webBrowser.Document.GetElementById("Deffensive_txt_id").InnerText = Password_txt.Text;

                LoginScreen_webBrowser.Document.GetElementById("maxdeffence_button_id").InvokeMember("Click");

                LoginScreen_webBrowser.Document.GetElementById("maxoffence_button_id").InvokeMember("Click");

                LoginScreen_webBrowser.Document.GetElementById("submit_button_id").InvokeMember("Click");

            }
            catch (MissingFieldException exc)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(exc.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're using Firefox, there's an extension called [iMacros](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/imacros-for-firefox/) which is able to do exactly what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I am using a web browser in the form. It's no specific web browser, it is 1 that is put in the form .